# Google Sitemap errors, which i cannot explain looking at code

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, google-search-console

I have this error:

> Error: This XML tag has an invalid value. Please fix it and resubmit.

I have a script on the cs-cart software that generates the sites XML sitemap for Google / search engines however I get that error above in Google webmaster tools.

Script URL for sitemap: http://www.ambientlounge.com.au/index.php?dispatch=xmlsitemap.view

SEO Based URL for sitemap: http://www.ambientlounge.com.au/sitemap.xml

Errors from Google webmaster tools submit and testing;

[image]

Line 2393:

> 0.5

Line 2393:

> 2015-10-30
>
> http://www.ambientlounge.com.au/bean-bag-blog/natalia-cajide-of-paws-and-co.-whispers-about-the-a.l.pet-lounge.html

I copied and pasted the XML contents to my editor and went to line so assuming those are the lines but regardless of that, the file is generated from the PHP loop so surely if we a XML error would error before and also I see nothing wrong with those plus the are the same really as the rest.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the ***shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.***

Comment: Ok, started at 8am this morning and now 4am that response just finished me off lol can you simplify? was a problem with question? really thought i explained well with good detail.

Comment: If you check the code and question, there should not any debugging as nothing wrong with the code! its a mystery and asking for some professional advise from fellow developers.

Comment: Questions pointing to live site files are off topic, since when they are fixed they no longer represent the core of the problem. That seems to be the case here too. In future, if you can show the relevant code/config (e.g. a sitemap) in a code block, that will help preserve the essence of the question well into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of that priority element is invalid.

```
<priority/>
```

It has to be a value between `0.0` and `1.0`. The default value is `0.5`. You have two possible solutions for urls without a priority. Do not add a priority element or add it with the default value.

```
<priority>0.5</priority>
```